# History of my iPhone apps

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, iphone, history

Is there a way to know the last time I reinstalled a specific app?  Also, how many times I have reinstalled it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not—there is no way to know that without jailbreaking.

Comment: Not even with a jailbreak?

Comment: I've edited your answer to clarify that it's not possible without a jailbreak. If you have reason to believe that my answer will not work, feel free to edit your answer to expand it. —cc @patrix

Answer (score 0):

If you're jailbroken, you can check when you installed an app by going to the application's container in /var/mobile/Applications and check the date modified of the iTunesMetadata.plist.

There is no way to check how many times you have reinstalled an app, even with a jailbreak.